# Why sbt compile doesn't copy unmanaged resources to classpath?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

Could you tell me why `sbt compile` doesn't copy unmanaged resources to classpath? On the other hand `sbt package` does. As result I can't start debugging unless I invoke `package` call manually :(

I'm using SBT 0.12.1

Below is my build.sbt.

```
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings

assemblySettings

organization  := "com.zzz"

version       := "0.1"

scalaVersion  := "2.10.2"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-language:reflectiveCalls,postfixOps,implicitConversions", "-deprecation", "-feature", "-encoding", "utf8")

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <++= baseDirectory { base =>
    Seq( base / "src/main/webapp" )
}

jarName in assembly := "zzz.jar"

mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
    {
        case "rootdoc.txt" => MergeStrategy.discard
        case x => old(x)
    }
}

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.zzz.Boot")

name := "zzz"

// disable using the Scala version in output paths and artifacts
crossPaths := false

artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + "." + artifact.extension
}

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sprayVersion = "1.2-M8"
  val akkaVersion  = "2.2.0-RC1"
Seq(
  "io.spray"            %   "spray-servlet" % sprayVersion withSources(),
  "io.spray"            %   "spray-can"     % sprayVersion withSources(),
  "io.spray"            %   "spray-routing" % sprayVersion withSources(),
  "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"    % akkaVersion,
  "org.eclipse.jetty"       %   "jetty-webapp"  % "8.1.7.v20120910"     % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" %   "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container"  artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
  "net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner" % "htmlcleaner" % "2.2",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.2.3",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.1",
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.0",
  "com.romix.scala" % "scala-kryo-serialization" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.codehaus.jettison" % "jettison" % "1.3.3",
  "com.osinka.subset" %% "subset" % "2.0.1",
  "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.2.5" intransitive()
)
}

seq(Revolver.settings: _*)

seq(webSettings: _*)

seq(Twirl.settings: _*)
```

Comment: what does `show compile:unmanaged-resource-directories` returns?

Comment: @AlexIv `[info] List(C:\work\sideprojects\courierapp\server\src\main\resources, C:\work\sideprojects\courierapp\server\src\main\webapp)`

Comment: Can't you just use `src/main/resources/webapp` which would be included by default?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The job of `compile` is to compile sources, so it won't typically do anything related to processing resources.  However, the resources need to be in the class directory for `run`, `package`, `test`, `console`, and anything else that uses the `fullClasspath`.  This is done by `fullClasspath` combining `exportedProducts`, which are the classes and resources generated by the current project, and `dependencyClasspath`, which are the classpath entries from dependencies.

The appropriate solution depends on what needs the resources.  From the command line, run `exported-products` to do a `compile` as well as `copy-resources`.  Programmatically, you will typically want to depend on `fullClasspath` or `exportedProducts`.

As a side note, you can typically find out what tasks do what using [the inspect command](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings).