# How can I get SBT to copy some unmanaged resources on compile?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I've got the same issue as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566474/why-sbt-compile-doesnt-copy-unmanaged-resources-to-classpath).

I'd like SBT to copy some unmanaged resources (in my case config files) **on compile**, it doesn't work because of the reasons outlined in the linked issue.

I don't really understand if the answer in the linked issue helps me, but the reason I want it to do it on **compile** is that *I want the unmanaged resources to be copied when I do a Rebuild Project in IntelliJ.*

Is this possible in SBT?  Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: Rebuild project in intellij doesn't run sbt...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I seem to have come away with the impression that it does via the SBT plug-in. I actually went on a bit of a mission to try and find the truth on that are you able to share a source that confirms your statement please?

Comment: The fact that intellij builds using their internal "Make"

Comment: Ah I found this page from 2012, it implies to me that SBT is doing the incremental compilation under the hood. Is this out of date do you think?http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/

Comment: I don't know, I don't use intellij to build. Ever.

Comment: From that link, it is not SBT: So, bytecode is still generated by Scalac (and Javac), project format is still IDEA’s, but incremental compilation is now handled by SBT instead of IDEA (so, we don’t use SBT project model, only SBT compiler, that acts as a wrapper around Scalac).